# Why do i get exception: The configuration for the "log" component must contain a "__class" element

Tags: yii2

My actions:

1) I upgrade php from 7.0 to 7.2

2) I enabled some php7.2-modules

3) I deleted compose.lock and folder "vendor"

4) composer install

5) I try visit page, but i get exception.

My configurations:

```
$config = [
    // code
    'bootstrap' => ['log'],
    'components' => [
        'errorHandler' => [
            'errorAction' => 'site/error',
        ],
        'log' => [
            'traceLevel' => YII_DEBUG ? 3 : 0,
            'targets' => [
                [
                    'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                    'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
                ],
            ],
        ]
    ]
    // code
];
```

Comment: What is your yii2 ver. in composer.json file? Try to change it to ~2.0.14 according to: https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/15895